# ADD and COPY to merge the contents of a dir with the one already on the build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to assemble an image with some files that are stored along with my dockerfile. What I expect with COPY or ADD is a merge behavior. However, the file hierarchy is overwritten if I use theses instructions. As such, files from the parent image are no longer available if they were within the path. (huge issue if for instance I was to save some file on /etc/mycoolstuff/filehere)

When this happens I am not able to use apt-get any more

I also saw some advice to convert my files to a tar packaged, but nothing different was observed.

For clarity, this was one of the issues(builds if I change the order, but it ends broken anyway cause child images will not be able to use apt any longer):

```
ADD     build/image-base.tgz /
RUN     apt-get clean -y && \
            apt-get update && \
            apt-get install unzip -y --no-install-recommends && \
            apt-get install gosu -y --no-install-recommends && \
            apt-get clean -y && \
            apt-get autoclean -y && \
            apt-get autoremove -y && \
            rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease 
Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Can you post the command you executed?

Comment: The last one was: ADD  build/image-base.tgz /

Comment: there, I have a simple file structure with tomcat8 config: etc/tomcat8/catalina.properties for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging I was able to find a workaround with COPY and a RUN to achieved the behavior I was looking for.

```
COPY    build/image-base.tgz /

RUN     tar -xvf image-base.tgz --no-overwrite-dir
```

Unfortunately this creates a new layer and the base tar will remain there. It is not a bit issue if it is just some text config files.

A weird way to get around the COPY instruction was to use wget, and untar afterwards, so we can delete the tar file. wget will do the trick if we are on a build environment where artifacts are stored and URLs created for them...in that scenario we just need one RUN, keeping the house clean.

Answer (score 4):

Docker has multi-stage builds since 17.05: [Use multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

```
FROM busybox as builder
ADD build/image-base.tgz /tmproot/

FROM alpine:latest  
...
COPY --from=builder /tmproot /
...
```

Another example:

```
FROM busybox as builder
COPY src/etc/app /tmproot/etc/app
COPY src/app /tmproot/usr/local/app

FROM alpine:latest  
...
COPY --from=builder /tmproot /
...
```

Comment: Definitely cool! This seems to be what I was looking for back then. I have not tested if the result is as good as the tar/download approach in terms of size. But seems nice.

Comment: The last `COPY` will create a new layer that overwrites everything from the base image, duplicating the base. Maybe starting from `scratch` would be better?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve?  Do you really want to overwrite the root directory?  Then you better build images from ***scratch***.  To do this, your Dockerfile must begin with `FROM scratch`

An official Docker tutorial on the subject, with scripts for multiple distros:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/

Comment: That is a good tip. I checked it out and upvoted. but this was not actually what I was looking for as I "really" wanted to overwrite from root. A minor detail that justify that this was not what I was looking for: the preposition - I was trying to overwrite from and not "the" directory. The merge behavior is quite desirable, and there is actually a big discussing on github - I fund it latter.

Comment: The merge will create another layer that will make your image bigger...  You can do the merge in the .tgz before the `docker build` and build the image from `scratch`.

Comment: agreed, but it is really not worth it to build a what would be possibly a buggy image just because of a few bytes of config files. I would have to go check what the authors did on the original one and miss updates. This would be good if I was to pack my own software from scratch using a distro as base, but I am trying to extend another image which is solid as a rock and other 2 official ones.. anyway we are discussing two different solutions for two different problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Azure [DevOps Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) (windows agent) as well as [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) and find the **merge happens automatically**.  Perhaps you should update your Docker version or try again to see if the merge is indeed happening as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is a pretty old issue/question, so versions might have certain importance as mentioned. However, you missed the point of why the question was made. First, we do not use windows for anything or the desktop provided by docker. second, merging (flattering) was always an option but it interfere with the ability to share layers across images... I do not really know about azure resources, we use Google or AWS, so I might be missing something here. But thanks anyway, maybe someday in the future I would be able to use your advice.